# Postgres query to get last date value for period along with sum for period?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, aggregate

I can't seem to understand how to do a simple thing in a single query.

I have a table containing balance of items present in system at end of every day:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (
    item character varying(10),
    storage_date date,
    qty integer
);

COPY t1 (item, storage_date, qty) FROM stdin;
A       2021-01-01      10
A       2021-01-02      10
A       2021-01-03      10
A       2021-01-04      5
A       2021-01-05      3
B       2021-01-01      1
B       2021-01-02      2
B       2021-01-03      100
B       2021-01-04      50
\.
```

**I need to get average number of items stored per period along with the balance of each item at the end of period.**

Let's say the period is between 2021-01-01 and 2021-01-05 .

Now, of course, average is simply:

```
SELECT item, sum(qty)/5 FROM t1 GROUP BY item ORDER BY item;
 item | avg
------+-----
 A    |   7
 B    |  30
(2 rows)
```

But I need it to also include the balance (qty) for each item for the last date of the period = 2021-01-05  (As you can see, item B also has no entry for that date, meaning the stock was 0 at that point. But it is OK, if it is either NULL or 0). **Wanted**:

```
 item | avg | balance at end of period
------+-----+---------
 A    |   7 |   3
 B    |  30 |  NULL
(2 rows)
```

I tried to use last_value() aggregate function:

```
SELECT item,last_value(qty) OVER (ORDER BY storage_date),sum(qty)/5 from t1 group by 1,2;
```

But that obviously doesn't work (I am not fluent at more advanced SQL; JOINS, GROUP BY and HAVING is what I understand).

What am I missing? Surely there must be some simple way rather than writing two queries?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a subquery:

```
SELECT item, sum(qty)/5, balance
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             FIRST_VALUE(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY item ORDER BY storage_date DESCk) as balance
      FROM t1
     ) t1
GROUP BY item, balance
ORDER BY item;
```

You can do this without a subquery as well:

I'm not sure why you are using `SUM(qty) / 5` instead of `AVG(qty)`, but that logic is from your query.

```
SELECT item, sum(qty)/5,
       (ARRAY_AGG(qty ORDER BY storage_date DESC))[1] as balance
FROM t1
GROUP BY item
ORDER BY item;
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution with subquery produces 7 rows instead of 2. The array_agg seems to work. I use /5 because I wasn't sure how PG will treat NULL values. They must be treated as 0, so if a period is 5 days, average is /5 not by /4 if there are only 4 entries present.

Comment: @Gnudiff . . . Then your logic is correct.

Comment: Also, your solution is great if there *is* entry for each day. In my case, when going for full period (5 days), the array_agg produces balance for day 4 for item B, as there is no entry for day 5 for it in data. It should be either NULL or 0 for B.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT ta.*, tb.qty
FROM(
   SELECT item, sum(qty)/5 
   FROM t1 
   GROUP BY item) ta
LEFT JOIN  t1 tb ON ta.item = tb.item AND tb.storage_date = TO_DATE('20210105','YYYYMMDD')
ORDER BY item;
```

Comment: This seems to work perfectly. I was hoping to avoid self JOINs, but it is probably for the best.